# PHPMailer sends email 3 times to each user

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmailer

When I run below code it fetches email from the database and sends mail 3 times to each user. I don't know what's wrong in my script. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'vendor\autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

include 'connection.php';

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `newspaper_subscriber` WHERE 
status = '1'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {

    $emails[$rows->subscriber_email] = $rows->subscriber_email;
}
}
foreach ($emails as $row) {
        $mail->setFrom('xyz@gmail.com', 'xyz');
        $mail->Subject = 'Weekly Newspaper';
        $mail->Body = 'For unsubscribe email us at 
        xyz@gmail.com';
        $mail->AddAddress($row);
        $mail->isSMTP();

        $path = __DIR__."\/01.pdf";
        $mail->addAttachment($path, "newspaper.pdf");
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Username = 'xyz@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = 'xyzxyz';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->send();

}
```

Comment: Did you make sure your database doesn't contain duplicate e-mail-addresses? Try GROUP BY subscriber_email in your query or array_unique on the addresses.

Comment: there are only three subscribers in the database.

Comment: @Select0r first subscriber gets mail 3 times, second gets two times and 3 one gets one time.

Comment: Don't know about your PhpMailer-class, but it seems like a lot of the parameters are the same for each mail and could be moved out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to clear address as in loop it will preserve existing address

so use something like this in loop also

```
  foreach ($emails as $row) {
      $mail->ClearAddresses();  
      $mail->ClearCCs();
      $mail->ClearBCCs();
      //rest of the code
```

Comment: Thank you so much It's Working Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

"AddAddress" will obviously add a recipient to already existing ones.
So first subscriber gets added, receives a mail, second subscriber gets added ON TOP, so during the second run in the loop, the first subscriber gets another mail (because the instance of the $mail has two recipients now) ... then in the third iteration the third subscriber gets added ON TOP, so during the third run the first one gets its third mail. Don't try this with a million recipients :)

I don't know how your PhpMailer-class works but you'll need to clear your recipients after each send() or use something different than "AddAddress" (e.g. "SetAddress" if there's such a thing in that class).